# concatenate string in python only if string matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of names in a list like this

```
names = ['Test', 'Test 2', 'Test 3', 'Unknown']
```

and I converted them from a list into a string by doing the follow:

```
test = ', '.join(names)
```

I would like to join the list as I am doing so but I want to ignore if the name if it is Unknown.

How can I get this done efficiently?

I can do this but this may not be the best way to do it since I am looping twice:

```
arr = []
   for n in names:
      if n != 'Unknown':
         arr.append(n)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following list comprehension:

```
', '.join([i for i in names if i!='Unknown'])
# 'Test, Test 2, Test 3'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can recreate the list first, without the Unknown, so you would do:

```
names = [element for element in names if element.lower() != "unknown"]
```

Or just add directly in the line during the join:

```
test = ', '.join([element for element in names if element.lower() != "unknown"])
```

PS: See that I added a code that would consider the filter as case insensitive

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to loop twice, you should iterate your list likely the same way you did but starting from names[1] and doing concatenations like this:

```
test = names[0]
for name in names[1:]:
    if name != 'Unknown':
        test += ', '+name
```